# drop all duplicate values in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have the following dataframe in Python:

```
A = [['A',2,3],['A',5,4],['B',8,9],['C',8,10],['C',9,20],['C',10,20]]
B = pd.DataFrame(A, columns = ['Col1','Col2','Col3'])
```

[image]

This gives me the above dataframe: I want to remove the rows that have the same values for Col1 but different values for Col3. I have tried to use drop_duplicates command with different subset of columns but it does not give what I want. I can write for loop but that is not efficient at all (since you might have much more columns than this).

```
C= B.drop_duplicates(['Col1','Col3'],keep = False)
```

[image]

Can anyone help if there is any command in Python can do this without using for loop?

The expected output would be, since A and C are removed because they have the same Col1 but different Col3.

[image]

Comment: Is the table at the bottom your desired output? If not then please add one.

Comment: What is your expected output? You've been given some... creative... ways of producing the exact same output you already have, but "Same values for Col1 but different values for Col3" is extremely unclear.

Comment: @BeRT2me  just added the expected output.

Comment: @Zero Added expected output.

Comment: @BeRT2me, no your solution will not work in general case. What if I have two rows with the same Col1 and Col3,then your solution removes them, but I want to keep them.

Comment: Please show such a test case, since your explanation still doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score -1):

This can do the job,

```
grouped_df = df.groupby("Col1")
groups = [grouped_df.get_group(key) for key in grouped_df.groups.keys() if len(grouped_df.get_group(key)["Col3"].unique()) == 1]
new_df = pd.concat(groups).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Output -

|  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | B | 8 | 9 |

Comment: This is the same output as OPs given `B.drop_duplicates(['Col1','Col3'],keep = False)`, I'm pretty sure that means it's not what they want...

Comment: I added the expected output.

Answer (score -1):

```
A = [['A',2,3],['A',5,4],['B',8,9],['C',8,10],['C',9,20],['C',10,20]]
df = pd.DataFrame(A, columns = ['Col1','Col2','Col3'])

output = df.drop_duplicates('Col1', keep=False)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
  Col1  Col2  Col3
2    B     8     9
```

Comment: But your code has the same output as OPs and ours. I asked for a desired output from OP so let's see what they want.

Comment: Ye, mine is incorrect as well lol, but it's the best wrong answer :')

Comment: Tbh I have written a very dumb way of solving this problem. It's just a one line answer.